# Timestamp shifting in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to shift timestamp to the next 6h P.M, but I have no clue how to do it in mySQL. Timestamps concerned are range from 7h P.M to 6 A.M, which means it can be the next day after the operation. My actual request is:

```
UPDATE issues 
SET due_date = due_date - (due_date % 86400) + (18 * 3600) 
WHERE HOUR(due_date) < 6
```

but it sounds hardcore and it doesn't work for due_dates after 6pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is after 6pm, add another 86400 seconds to go to the next day.

```
UPDATE issues
SET due_date = IF(HOUR(due_date) < 6,
                  due_date - (due_date % 86400) + (18 * 3600),
                  due_date - (due_date % 86400) + (18 * 3600) + 86400)
```

Comment: This was simple. I shouldn't code while eating... Thx, have a nice day !

Comment: @GwyndionFR your `due_date % 86400` is sketchy at best.  You should be using the built-in date/time functions, not raw numbers, to filter and manipulate time.